# Setting SKSpriteNode from UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, skspritenode, sktexture

I am having trouble setting a SKSpriteNode from a UIImage. I am using a bridge on the UIImage, converting the image to an SKTexture, and then creating a new SKSpriteNode with that SKTexture, but my code keeps crashing with the following alert "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)"

```
CGImageRef textureImage =  (__bridge CGImageRef)(theUIImage);
SKTexture *heroTexture = [SKTexture textureWithCGImage:textureImage];
SKSpriteNode *hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:heroTexture size:CGSizeMake(64, 64)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bridging the UIImage to CGImageRef, you should use:

```
CGImageRef textureImage = [theUIImage CGImage];
```

If your image is not nil, it should work.

Also, you could try:

```
SKTexture *heroTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:theUIImage];
```

A little tip; always check for "nullity".

Comment: I've tried with and without the bridge and my thread is still crashing! I've also tested to make sure the image is not nil (I added a UIImageView set to the image for testing). The code works fine when I instantiate using a local image though:
        SKSpriteNode *hero= [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"hero.png" normalMapped:YES];

Comment: So, what's the source of the "theUIImage"?

Comment: I am taking a photo using the camera and setting it as theUIImage

Comment: I think it can be about the image. You should also check the CGImageRef if it's 0 or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a texture using the image: `[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:...]` and then use this to creat the Sprite: `[SKSprite spriteWithTexture:....]`. (It could be SpriteFromTexture)